# Could not getting firebase token from shared preference?

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging in our app to displaying push notifications. According to FirebaseInstanceId doc.

When a new user installs my app, the onTokenRefresh() is automatically being called.

Now i want to send token to my server to store it in database. token are store in database with null. so i could not getting tokens from shared preference.

InstanceIdService Code :

```
public class FcmInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),recent_token);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

On Button click i am sending token to server, code:

```
String app_server_url = "http://192.168.1.1/fcm/fcm_insert.php";

btnSendFcm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),"");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),token+"-1-",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, app_server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("fcm_token",token);

            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
}
});
```

As i am checking shared preference data on my device, there are two files created :-
1)com.google.android.gms.appid.xml
2)com.google.android.gms.measurement.prefs.xml

Data in com.google.android.gms.appid.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="|T|119518470744|*">{&quot;token&quot;:&quot;here are some data&quot;,&quot;appVersion&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;timestamp&quot;:1481693481269}</string>
    <string name="|S||P|">here are some data</string>
    <string name="|S|cre">here are some data</string>
    <string name="|S||K|">here are some data</string>
</map>
```

I have checked many articles on it but could not resolve it. anybody can suggest me what i have to do for it.

Comment: Did you declare `FcmInstanceIdService` in your manifest as [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService)?

Comment: Does your app really return a valid token? Check for that first whether the SharedPreferences is saving a string or a null value. Try a toast and let know of it. Also, add the supporting class mentioned by @qbix

Comment: Yes it's saving a valid token and when i copy this token and save it to my database and send notification via my server....notification working but issue is that token is not saving to database.

Comment: Another option would be to not store the token in shared preferences at all. Just call `FirebaseInstanceID.getInstance().getToken()` when it is time to deliver the token to the server.

Comment: i tried but it's not working... i don't know whats going on..

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, the only thing i can imagine, is that the "application context" is not the same inside FCM's "onTokenRefresh()" and in the rest of the application. Did you managed to save it and retrieve it?